# Multiple keyframes animations

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want an arrow first to fade-in on my site in 1.5 seconds, and after 3 seconds I want it to do a little bounce movement to indicate a scroll movement. I want to repeat the bounce animation every 3rd second but the fade-in only once (when I reload the page).

My code now:

```
arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 85vh;
  animation: arrowInn 1.5s ease-in forwards, arrowBounce 1s 2s ease-in;
}

@keyframes arrowInn{
  from{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to{
    opacity: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes arrowBounce {
  0% { bottom: 0px; }
  50% { bottom: 10px; }
  100% { bottom: 0px; }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more on the issue you are facing. It would be helpful if you can provide a working fiddle for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already working, you just forgot to add `infinite` on your second animation:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 10px;
  animation: arrowInn 1.5s ease-in forwards, arrowBounce 1s 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes arrowInn {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 100%; }
}

@keyframes arrowBounce {
  0% { bottom: 10px; }
  50% { bottom: 0; }
  100% { bottom: 10px; }
}
```

```html
<div>⬇️</div>
```

Also, if you want to make it bounce from the `bottom` you have to set the `bottom` property instead of the `top` on your element. I reversed your `arrowBounce` animation to make it start from `10px` instead of `0`, but this part is up to you.

Comment: Really dont get it... My code in my project is exactly the same and still i dont get the bounce, just the fade in... Im doing the animation on an SVG image, that should not have anything to with the problem?

Comment: The SVG doesn't change anything, check the inspector to see if the styles are correctly applied. Maybe you have something that overwrite the `bottom` property on your element.